# Can Sub-Users share the same list of Dynamic Templates?

Tags: twilio, sendgrid

My team uses SendGrid Pro 100k. We currently do not use Twilio Sub Users, but I'm thinking about setting up a test environment sub user and a production sub user to split test traffic from production traffic. I like that each sub-user has it's own event webhooks, but I want to share dynamic templates across the non-prod and prod sub user so that testing is the same. Is this possible?